# Linha tracejada apenas css?

Tags: css

alguém sabe como fazer esta linha tracejada apenas com css? já tentei com imagens porém não consegui obrigado!
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tracejada como? Pela imagem não dá pra entender.

Comment: Você pode usar `border-style:dashed`, mas não vai ficar como na imagem. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/border-style

Comment: por que só pode ser com css? Usando duas tags span da para reproduzir tranquilamente com `border-style`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quer o traço da forma colocada na imagem da pergunta, você pode criar uma classe com os *[pseudo-elementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos)* `::before` e `::after`:

```css
/* tirei o underline do "a" apenas para exemplificar no resultado*/
a{
   text-decoration: none;
}

.trasso{
   position: relative;
}

.trasso::before,
.trasso::after{
   content: '';
   border-bottom: 2px solid #090;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
}

.trasso::before{
   width: 5px;
   left: 0;
}

.trasso::after{
   width: 30px;
   left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p class="trasso">Conheça o projeto</p>
   <a href="#" class="trasso">Conheça o projeto</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Da para fazer com `linear-gradient`

```css
.linha {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #48958C;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    position: relative;
}
.linha::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 6rem;
   height: 0.2rem;
   top: 100%;
   left: 0.25rem;
   background: linear-gradient(to right,#48958C 0%, #48958C 15%, transparent 15%, transparent 30%, #48958C 30%)
}
```

```html
<p class="linha">Conheça o projeto</p>
```